# Any datatype can convert into string except Object type when we are doing type conversion? why Object have that nature?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert one data type to string. All data types are executing well except Object type, Why?

Example:

All these are converting well

```
console.log("" + 2); // "2"
console.log("" + true); // "true"
console.log("" + [1,2,3,4,5,6])// "1,2,3,4,5,6"
console.log("" + undefined); // "undefined"
console.log("" + null); // "null"
```

But, getting problem with the following

```
console.log("" + {name : "srinivas", age : 23, qualification : 
"B.tech"})//"[object Object]"
```

Comment: Looks like it worked; when you convert an object to a string, you get the string `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: You might read ECMA-262 on what [*Object.prototype.toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring) does. If you want it to do something else, replace it (not advised) or create your own object constructor and give it your special *toString* method.

Comment: Or, if your object does not contain cyclic references - you can simply use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @IVOGELOV `JSON.stringify()` can be used even with cyclic objects if you use its second parameter to filter out already-seen objects.